# MySQL: Select entries that contain only elements from a list and their combinations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains single words (e.g., A, B, and C) and compound words (e.g., AB, AC, and AD). I want to select all entries that contain only words from a predefined word list.

Example

```
id   word
--   -----
1    A
2    B
3    C
4    D
5    AB
6    AC
7    AD
```

Given the list ('A','B'), I want to select the words A, B, and AB. That is, I want to filter out everything that contains something other than A or B.

When I use 
`SELECT * from table WHERE word in ('A','B')`, I only get A and B, without the compound AB.

When I use `SELECT * from table WHERE word like '%A%' or word like '%B%'`, I get A, B, AB, AC, and AD.

Basically, I could do the following:

- Step 1: `SELECT word from table WHERE word not like '%A%' and word not like '%B%'` which returns C and D.
- Step 2: `SELECT * from table WHERE word not like '%C%' and word not like '%D%'`, which returns A, B, and AB.

However, I don't know how to combine the two queries. I've read about subqueries, but they don't work with the like statement.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a regular expression.  I think:

```
where word regexp '^[AB]+'
```

This assumes that "word" really means "letter".  You can revise this for actual words.

Comment: Actually it's Japanese Kanji, but it should work the same way as in the example. Can regular expression also match different combinations such as AB and BA? In the real application, the word list will contain some hundred characters and match against a whole dictionary, so there will be quite a few combinations.

Comment: @JakobFörster . . . You should probably be looking into full text index solutions.